# Cardinality of union of sets of a given cardinality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I know that:

1. finite union of finite sets is a finite set
2. countable union of countable sets is a countable set

It is possible to characterize the sets $C$ of cardinals satisfying the following property?

> for every set $\mathscr S$ of cardinality belonging to $C$ whose members are sets of cardinality belonging $C$, the union:
> $$\bigcup_{S\in\mathscr S}S$$
> is a set of cardinality belonging to $C$.

If $C$ is the set of finite cardinals $\omega$, then we get 1.
If $C=\omega\cup\{\aleph_0\}$, then we get 2.

Comment: Finite is not "a cardinality", the union of two sets with two elements can be anywhere between two and four elements.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I edited the post by considering a set of cardinals instead of a single cardinal.

Comment: The question makes less sense to me now, to be honest. And I've posted an answer to the original one, which now I'm not sure answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here which you somewhat merge together.

First, the naive answer, $c$ is either $0$ or $1$, or any infinite cardinal. To see that, note that $c^2=c$ holds exactly in those cases. Now for each $S\in\scr S$ choose a bijection with $c$, and we just get $c^2$.

Now, what about the "finite unions of finite sets are finite"? That's not really a cardinality. Instead, this is "the union of fewer than $\aleph_0$ sets, each of size less than $\aleph_0$ is also smaller than $\aleph_0$". So the question is "If $|\mathscr S|< c$ and each $S\in\scr S$, $|S|<c$, then $|\bigcup\mathscr S|<c$".

This is exactly the same as claiming that $c$ is a regular cardinal, which includes all the successor cardinals, $\aleph_0$, and the (weakly) inaccessible cardinals.